# Comparing Serial input in arduino

Tags: arduino, esp8266, string-comparison, arduino-uno

I am doing a simple project to control leds by arduino via website made on ESP8266.
The data is transmitted correctly by ESP8266 but arduino code is not working properly.
the serial monitor on Arduino reads the recieved data correctly but nothing turns ON.
I am using Serial.println() on ESP8266 to send data.
Code for arduino:
'''

```
#include <String.h>

#define L1 2
#define L2 3
#define L3 4

String str = "";

void setup() {
// Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
Serial.begin(250000);
pinMode(L1,OUTPUT);
pinMode(L2,OUTPUT);
pinMode(L3,OUTPUT);

while (!Serial) {
; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
}
}

void loop() { // run over and over
if (Serial.available()) {
str = Serial.read();
Serial.write(Serial.read()); 
if (str == ("ALLN"))
{
  digitalWrite(L1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(L2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(L3,HIGH);
}
else if (str == ("ALLFF"))
{
  digitalWrite(L1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(L2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(L3,LOW);
}
else if (str == ("L1N"))
{
  digitalWrite(L1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(L2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(L3,LOW);
}
else if (str == ("L1L2N"))
{
  digitalWrite(L1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(L2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(L3,LOW);
}
else if (str == ("L1L3N"))
{
  digitalWrite(L1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(L2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(L3,HIGH);
}
else if (str == ("L2N"))
{
  digitalWrite(L1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(L2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(L3,LOW);
}
else if (str == ("L2L3N"))
{
  digitalWrite(L1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(L2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(L3,HIGH);
}
else if (str == ("L3N"))
{
  digitalWrite(L1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(L2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(L3,HIGH);
}
else 
{
  digitalWrite(L1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(L2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(L3,LOW);
}
}
}
```

'''
Please Help!

Comment: How do you know the Arduino is reading the data correctly? Are you aware that `Serial.read()` reads a single byte of data (according to the [documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/read/))? Lookup `Serial.readString()` or `Serial.readStringUntil()`.

Comment: When I use those two functions you specified ' Serial.readString() ' and  ' Serial.readStringUntil() '. the complete output does not appear on the serial monitor only the first letter appears .

Comment: I suspect you aren't using them correctly as your code has  other issues. You have two calls to `Serial.read()`. One to get the input, then another to write to the serial console. What you are writing to the monitor is not what you are reading for your input since they're two separate reads. Try `str = Serial.readStringUntil("\n");` followed by `Serial.println(str)`.

Comment: I tried to use the method given in the answer below and the serial data is read perfectly. But when I use ' inputString == anotherstring ' or even ' inputString == "anotherstring" ' or use ' inputString.equals(anotherstring) ' in if statement it does not work nothing is happenening.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the SerialEvent

```
String inputString = "";
bool stringComplete = false;
void loop() {
    if(stringComplete) doStuff(); //compareString for example
    //empty the inputString and change stringComplete to false when done comparing
}
void serialEvent() {
    while(Serial.available()) {
        char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
        inputString += inChar;
        if(inChar == "\n") stringComplete = true;
    }
}
```

[Reference](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/SerialEvent)

Comment: I tried this method and the serial data is read perfectly.
But when I use ' inputString == anotherstring ' or even ' inputString == "anotherstring" '
or use ' inputString.equals(anotherstring) ' in  if statement it does not work nothing is happenening.

Comment: Try to put the inputString += inChar; in a else of the if(inChar == "\n"). So if there is a new line to not add it to the inputString